# Excel sort table value and return row names of the 5 largest rows

Tags: excel

As stated in the title, the  table has two columns, one for row names and the other is for values, I just want to return the row names and values of the 5 rows with the largest value accordingly back to another range of cells. (It will be better if I don't have to operate the table)

Thank you very much!

for example the table is like:
      Johnny 1
      Harry  2
      Jessie 3
Luke   4
Mary   2
Lucy   1
Peter  5

Basically I would like the ouput to be 
Peter 5
Luke  4
Jessie 3
Harry 2
Mary 2

Comment: could you show us an example and the desired output?

Comment: To get a meaningful answer please read the FAQ with instructions http://www/stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and a personal favorite of mine: http://www.mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried

Comment: Your question is vague, but I suggest you looking into `=LARGE()` formula.

Comment: @PeterRing Hey I just updated the question(sorry that I don't know how to input a table formate) but I guess the answer from Graffl is working though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fifth biggest number you get like this

```
=LARGE($B$1:$B$10;5)
```

and then you will find the row number of this value with MATCH and use this in INDEX to get the text value

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10;MATCH(LARGE($B$1:$B$10;5);$B$1:$B$10))
```

Now this will not work, if you have values appearing twice. Then an additional column could help or some more complicated trick for the MATCH part, like

```
MATCH(LARGE(B1:B10-ROW(B1:B10)/1000;1);B1:B10-ROW(B1:B10)/1000;0)
```

And then you have to make an array function out of the formula but pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` not only ENTER. Then `{}` will be added around the formula.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it seems the code LARGE(B1:B10-ROW(B1:B10)/1000;1) does not provide a valid result. Is it because after calculation, the result is no longer a reference?

Comment: Do you know about matrix formulas in Excel (things with '{...}')? If not, then you have to look it up and understand that first before you can use this.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? What I find are mostly related to the if statement. Sorry that I cannot vote for you here.

Comment: Ok. I elaborated/edited a bit. I know you cannot vote for me, that is fine, but you can mark my answer as the answer to your question, if it helped indeed.